# custom activity animation, can't find @anim/ resource

Tags: android, animation

I want a custom animation for one activity, I use code like this:

```
<style name="WCCAnimation.LoadingImageShow" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/zoom_enter</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
</style>
```

But the problem is that Eclipse displays:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'android:activityCloseExitAnimation'   with value
>   '@anim/slide_out_left').

I'm sure slide_out_left.xml file is in sdk's anim folder.

I tried some other animation under anim folder, still don't work.

---

I just follow the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087366/displaying-activity-with-custom-animation) case, but for me, just can't find resource under @anim.

Answer (score 0):

If

> slide_out_left.xml file is in sdk's anim folder

As You mentioned, then provide path to android resource like: `@android:anim/slide_out_right`.

And please note, that not all resources from platform files can be used in Your app, sometimes You might need just copy exact xml to your app.

Comment: when I copy this file to my own folder, this line of the file:slide_out_left.xml has error: <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   error: Invalid start tag 
 set

Comment: Are You placing it to anim folder? Could You specify exact platform You copied animation file from and Your project platform level? Actually, <set> tag should be ok - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html .

Comment: I place it in style folder and I use @style/ to import it.  I think the problem is not this.  I found other people can just use @anim/xxx without any problem.  BTW, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You definitely should place animation resources into anim folder. <set> is wrong tag for style xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code in your layout for which you want animate.And apply scaling or alpha effects to your animation xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layoutAnimation="@anim/zoom_enter"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
```