# Android: Activity close animation not working

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am trying to make new activities pull in from the right, then when they close, push back to the right, back where they came from. I realized that only the `activityOpenEnterAnimation` and `activityOpenExitAnimation` items were actually being used; so no matter what, the animation is ALWAYS in from left, out to right.

```
    <style name="MySlideAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
        <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    </style>
```

Am I missing something which enables the `activityCloseEnterAnimation` and `activityCloseExitAnimation`?
PS I am hoping to stick with xml themes etc if possible, as opposed to java.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087366/displaying-activity-with-custom-animation

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @just8laze, I gave up with this method in the end, but if I were to approach the problem now I would resort to Java.

Comment: This is how I would go about it -  
After the parent activity's `startAcitvity()`, AND to the child activity's `onBackPressed()` I would add: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_exit` 
Hope this helps