# How to control the width or the visibility of an activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm using this awesome library **[Dragger](https://github.com/ppamorim/Dragger)** to add drag features to my activity, but is there a way to limit the width of the activity when it shows up or dragged..!? I don't want it to fill the entire screen..! kinda like the drawer navigation menu *(see the pic below)*.

I was thinking of Dialog Activity, but it seems to be concerned with dialogs only and won't allow filling the other 3 sides or I not fully understand it..!

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is not a view, so it does not have a size. Its' layout views do however.
You can try changing their sizes. Or, as it is an animation lib, you can try modifying existing or adding your own animations where views change sizes when moving. You can modify this param:

```
 <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087366/displaying-activity-with-custom-animation) might help you.